# Post Attachment missing head (stylesheets/js/what-not)

Tags: posts, attachments, wp-head

I am using a modified 2011 theme, I got the single post to look fine but my single attachment is not working.

I'm told this will default to the page.php if I do not have an attachment template. So, it doesn't look like its pulling the head from page.php either.

Thanks in advance for any help, i'd provide some code but i'm not sure where to start. derp.

Comment: It uses `single.php` if `attachment.php` is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is with the template hierarchy flow chart. http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png I'm always consulting this page.

When you say modified twenty eleven, what do you mean? The image.php file is what handles image attachment pages in twenty eleven. I'm not familiar entirely with how it works, but it may be also making a call to the content-image.php file where `the_content()` function is being invoked, maybe. Not sure.

Hopefully this'll at least get you pointed in the right direction though.